# HTML/CSS/JS Drag-Scroll isn't scrolling container vertically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to put together a local html file, where I have a repeating background, and the user can click+drag to scroll around an image inside of a div. I've gotten this far by frankensteining a lot of code from various sources (especially Phuoc Nguyen), but I'm not understanding why the click+drag wont let me scroll the image vertically, only left to right. Any insight would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test scroll</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <style>
        body {
            background-image:url("img/background.png");
        }
        img {
            pointer-events: none;
            user-select: none;
            width: 100vw;
        }
        .container {
            cursor: grab;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const ele = document.getElementById('container');
        
            let pos = { top: 0, left: 0, x: 0, y: 0 };

            const mouseDownHandler = function (e) {
                ele.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
                ele.style.userSelect = 'none';
            
                pos = {
                    // The current scroll
                    left: ele.scrollLeft,
                    top: ele.scrollTop,
                    // Get the current mouse position
                    x: e.clientX,
                    y: e.clientY,
                };
        
            document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
            document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);
            };
        
            const mouseMoveHandler = function (e) {
                // How far the mouse has been moved
                const dx = e.clientX - pos.x;
                const dy = e.clientY - pos.y;

                // Scroll the element
                ele.scrollTop = pos.top - dy;
                ele.scrollLeft = pos.left - dx;
            };
        
            const mouseUpHandler = function () {
                document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
                document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);

                ele.style.cursor = 'grab';
                ele.style.removeProperty('user-select');
            };
            
            ele.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownHandler);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" class="container">
        <img src="img/connections.png" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The image I'm attempting to scroll is vertical, so I have it's width set to 100vw, and I would like the user to click and drag up/down to view the entire thing. I feel like some property in my CSS is preventing it from scrolling properly, but I've tried adding/removing/tweaking the properties I have already without success.